# UICollectionViewCells inside UICollectionView embedded in UITableViewCell being repeated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I Followed this tutorial on how to embed UICollectionViews inside UITableViewCells: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Only difference is that the custom cells I'm using contain a button and a label, the button increments the label number by one.

The problem I'm facing is that the UICollectionViewCell items are being repeated after a few rows for each UITableViewCell, I tried resetting the UITableViewCell using prepareForReuse() and that solved the repeat issue, but now whenever I scroll the quantities are gone and the cell is reset.

Answer (score 0):

Try and reload the embedded collectionview.

I have had a similar issue where I had tableviews embedded into collectionview cells, and the tableviews would show the same data after scrolling since the collectionview cell was being reused. I solved it by simply calling reloadData() on the nested tableview. It's the opposite situation for you but I feel like the problem is similar.